# Storing iPhone application settings in app

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, settings, user-preferences

My iPhone app has few settings that users is likely to change quite often. I would like to know if there's any suggested way of handling such settings (reading and saving them). On Apple sites I found only a tutorial about integrating your application settings with Settings app ([link](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationSettings/ApplicationSettings.html)) but I don't want a user to exit my app so he could just change the option.

Is there any default mechanism to handle such settings in app itself or do I have to implement a solution of my own?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Best and easiest way to store settings in the iPhone is through [`NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/UserDefaults.html). Keeps you from having to deal with the file system or plists or any of that other stuff.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *storedVal = @"This is what you want to save";
NSString *key = @"storedVal"; // the key for the data

[defaults setObject:storedVal forKey:key];
[defaults synchronize]; // this method is optional


// Get the results out
NSString *results = [defaults stringForKey:key];
```

Here's what Apple says on the types of objects you can store in the Defaults

> A default object must be a property
>   list, that is, an instance of (or for
>   collections a combination of instances
>   of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber,
>   NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If
>   you want to store any other type of
>   object, you should typically archive
>   it to create an instance of NSData.

There are some more caveats, like if you store an NSDictionary the key values must be strings.

Comment: Is it possible to store values of types other then `NSString` like numbers or dates?

Comment: Thanks mate, that's the kind of answer I wanted to hear.

Comment: Is there an advantage to doing this over just using a framework like "www.inappsettingskit.com" that Ortwin posted about?

Comment: @Greg inappsettingskit is great if that's what you want. This stuff is easy to implement, though. If you just have a few things you want to save, I'd say writing all the code yourself would be easier than integrating the settings kit into your app.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a UI to edit the settings from inside the app, check out InAppSettingsKit at http://www.inappsettingskit.com

Answer (score 0):

Read the [File and Networking Guide](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=file+and+networking+iphone+developer) from the iPhone Developer Connection. It will explain how you get the path for the different predefined locations in the application sandbox. I'd recommend that you use a NSDictionary to store your preferences which can easily be saved to the file system and converted into a plist.